# Where to get the "total" dividend (for a specific stock) from?

Tags: equities, data, dividends

I´m trying to build a Stock ranking/Picking model sorted by some kind of score.

For this I need the **total** dividend by Stock, let´s say for **AAPL** and **FCAU**

I have been checking several financial sites, but I only get the the dividend by share, not the total.

For example, on Yahoo:
[image: Apple]

or

[image: FIAT]

Comment: You could back into it from the dividend yield.  Dividend yields can be found everywhere.

Comment: It seems odd that you'd need the total dividend, but it would just be shares outstanding time DPS.